# Is there any point in handing back exams ordered by grade?

Tags: teaching, grades

Back in France I had a few teachers handing back exams in order from the highest grade to the lowest grade, and I recall there was some tense suspense, especially for for the people at the bottom of the stack. Is there any point in handing back exams ordered by grade? Assume there is no online platform to release grades.

Comment: Protecting because it's on list of "hot network questions," which tends to lead to answers from users of other SE sites who don't necessarily have any knowledge of academia.

Comment: @ff524 it'd be great if you could "protect" upvotes too, because once a question gets hot it can be quite poor (not worth downvotes, but not well researched!) and get more than a 'proper' question.

Comment: @AlecTeal What do you want me to add in the question?

Comment: @AlecTeal While I agree with you in spirit, I think this would run against common SE spirit. @ Franck I don't think there is anything wrong with *this* question, I understood Alec's point more as a question of principle, not a specific criticism of this question.

Comment: Funny that you mention this. When I hand back exams, I often make it a point to tell the students that I am **not** handing them back in any particular order, because sometimes I've sensed anxiety building in the room – no doubt because some students were wondering if I was following this practice.

Comment: @xLeitix Then he should post his comment on meta as a question.

Comment: To add some competitive incentive to do well

Comment: I remember my middle school teacher doing the opposite thing, ie. starting from lowest grades. It was a nice thing for students who underestimated their skills.

Answer (score 33):

No good reasons, only tradition (this is how we've always done it) and sadism (the poorer scoring students should be shamed into doing better). In the US, these days, at the college level at least, it also might now also be considered bordering on a FERPA violation by some. If you announced that the grades were returned in score order, but didn't reveal an actual number, you might get a pass, but I bet you'd get a lot of complaints. If you announced the scores as you did it, you'd definitely be in violation.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how the tradition started?

Comment: None whatsoever especially since I've never experienced it. I have experienced the posting of grades publicly by last name, last 4 digits of SSN/Student ID number, and the calling out of grades in a classroom setting. None of these are allowed here now both for privacy reasons (FERPA) and to protect the feelings of students (which is related).

Comment: Yeah, in the US grades are considered confidential information, so I'd be worried that passing them back sorted by grade could be construed as a violation.  And as a child I remember hating when my elementary school teachers did this.  I was almost always the top score, and it just made it so easy for the kids to know who to ostracize.  College students are a little bit more mature than that (I've seen semblances of the behavior in them at times, though), but even without the legal consideration I avoid this behavior out of bad memories.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt This is anecdotal and poorly sourced, but I have heard that French education has historically tended to embrace the practice of publicly shaming students who perform poorly, in order to push them to do better.  Handing back exams like this would be part and parcel with such a philosophy.

Comment: @jakebeal Good point, sounds true to me, though not necessarily targeted at shaming students who perform poorly, but any, and I think in the teachers' mindsets it's more about teasing, and as you say, well-intended.

Comment: _(which is related)_ — [citation needed] I find it very hard to believe that FERPA was ever intended to protect student's feelings.  Employment, credit, insurance, housing, and overall privacy, sure.  But feelings?

Comment: @JeffE, which is related to privacy not FERPA. Privacy just happens to be the thing that FERPA tries to protect. Sorry if it was confusing. People get upset if their privacy is violated. The state can take action to protect that.

Comment: @jakebeal I can confirm that from my own experience (as a grown-up in two separate French classes), and this was the reason given by French colleagues why they didn't want to speak English - they are indoctrinated to feel shameful about anything other than perfection. Terrifying system.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: it may not be intended to ashame students nowadays, but certainly in the past, in the era where bad students where forced to wear the *bonnet d'ane* (donkey hat). On the other side of the coins, it is also to honor good students: in my mother's era  (60's, 70's), good students received small awards from teachers (images,...) or from the city hall (dictionaries for example), and only good students could attend middle and high school. The book/movie *La gloire de mon pere*  is a great place to have a look on "old school" French educational system.

Comment: @l0b0 Anecdote as a reply: my aunt is French and has spoken English as part of her business for many many years (15-20). She doesn't speak English to her children *at all* because she's afraid her English isn't good enough (my uncle is American so he fills in). It's a very complex issue for French nationals, and quite honestly I don't know if it's something that can be changed without amending the education system in France. It's perhaps even deeper than that, a cultural issue that will continue to affect French citizens.

Answer (score 10):

When I was a student, some twenty years ago, there were two common ways to release grades after a written exam:

1. putting a notice on a board along the university corridors;
2. gathering all the students in a classroom and calling them one by one to the desk.

In the first case, the order on the notice was typically alphabetical. In the second, the order of the calls was frequently by grade, especially when written tests were followed by an oral examination to be started soon after the release of the grades. In this case, the motivation was probably that of practicality: it's easier to draw the boundary line between those who have to take the oral examination and those who failed.

A funny note: I recall an exam in which the professor listed first those who passed the exam, and I wasn't there; then he listed those who failed the exam... and I wasn't even there; lastly, he added minaciously: and then there's *Ortolano*...

Comment: So did you fail or pass? :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: I was borderline, but he admitted me to the oral examination, menacing of failing me at the first wrong word. I eventually passed the exam with a grade slightly above the bare minimum ;-)

Comment: @Joe: why new? It's old actually ;-)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano New to me (and that's probably why it's new!)

Answer (score 5):

I often sort essays by the grade so I can do a final check on the distribution and the consistency of the marking. We return essays through the school office, so the order does not matter. If I was handing them out to the class, for them not to be in grade order, I would have to introduce a random shuffle. Throughly shuffling 200+ essays would take a little time, likely in the critical 10 minutes before the start of class. That said, I would probably do it.

Comment: I agree, the only upside I could think of was to avoid shuffling the exams.

Comment: You probably wouldn't have to do a thorough shuffle, as long as no more than 2 or 3 at a time were in order. Even that might be overkill, as nobody except for the recipient sees his grade, and the order is unimportant unless people can guess what people got. That guess won't be exact, so probably just randomizing eight groups would be enough.

Comment: I also think that the underlying reason for sorting-by-grade is just that it makes some sanity checks easier.

Comment: You wouldn't need to shuffle, just grab them from a "random" point in the pile instead of from the top.

Comment: I agree with @Lohoris – you could also "cut the deck" three or four times. The order wouldn't be completely random, but it would only take 15 or 20 seconds to introduce some degree of unsortedness.

Comment: You check the grade distribution of 200+ exams without a computer, sorting them by hand?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Gives you time to think about the distribution as you discover it... :)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni we use letter grades so I just make 10 stacks on my desk. I can sort them pretty quick. And yes,  I could shuffle them pretty randomly in 30 seconds, the key would be remembering to do this before heading to class. Our support staff enters the grades, so I do not get an electronic breakdown until too late.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in a high school setting is that the pupils will be curious about how their friends did in the exam. If you hand back the exams in this way, you'll be able to resume the lessons very soon after you're done giving back the exams.

Comment: similarly students will try to establish how well they did, based on the difficulty of the exam (rather than on raw mark), and one way to do this is by comparison to students of known quality. Eg I know Bob is a really smart dude, I did better than Bob, so I must be doing OK. Or I know Sam never shows up to class, I did worse than him, I guess my failure wasn't cos the exam was hard, but because I don't know the content. Thus there is chatter and speculation as a attempt to work out true proficiency.
That said, I think a better way to know true proficiency is to release the mean and std dev.